# how can run laravel websocket on server?

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-websockets, virtualmin

Do you need a special configuration to run laravel websocket on the server?

I am running Laravel websocket on the server (ubonto with vitrualmin) and I am not getting any error when running.
My url has ssl and I added these values in the .env file

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT = /home/.../domains/api.....com/cellar/ssl/ssl.cert
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK =  /home/.../domains/api....com/cellar/ssl/ssl.key

PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

I also checked this issue on both `PUSHER_SCHEME=http`and`PUSHER_SCHEME=https` modes, but I also encounter this text in the browser: "pusher.min.js:8  WebSocket connection to `wss://api.....com:6001/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established`